# Is it possible to filter a datasource getting the condition from a calculated field?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm guessing if it is possible to filter a datasource using the result getted from a calculated field.

For example, I need to filter my datasource (and, in consequence) my grid, using the condition: `Field A - Field B > 0`.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a range on a field from your table (like its RecId, it does not matter which field you chose) and use an expression in its value (described here http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges).