# How to hide record in Form grid based on display method value?

Tags: forms, gridview, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a simple Form, in my *DataSource* I created a classic displayMethod (named *calculateAmount*) and use this metodod to show the value in Form's grid.

So It's possible to show only record having a specific value from *calculateAmount* , for example I want to show only record having *calculateAmount()* > 0 , other record with calculated *calculateAmount()* < 0 not show.

So if I can't mix Query and displayMethod, possibly where I can insert the condition (for example *active* *executeQuery* etc) ?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: If the calculated amount is calculated using existing table fields then this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312013/is-it-possible-to-filter-a-datasource-getting-the-condition-from-a-calculated-fi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following sequence:

1. Execute query is called and the AOT query is translated into SQL query
2. Results are fetched from SQL server after `executeQuery()`
3. Display method is called for **each record** and then the values are shown on grid

So you cannot add **query range** on `execute query` based on display method value.

One thing you can do:

1. Duplicate your datasource table and set its Table Type property to TempDB
2. In `executeQuery` method write the logic to fill this new created table
3. Here you can add this condition like this:

   `if ([your data source].calculateAmount() > 0)
   {
        // do not add the record in temp table
   }
   else
   {
        // add the record in temp table
   }`
4. Set your temp table as the datasource to your grid.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Or you can use a view with a computed column (provided you can compute the value with SQL). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx